# Got error with Windows credential in WCF : SecurityNegotiationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I specified ClientCredientialType as Username but Validating it using Windows So even after providing correct windows credentials I am getting error.

**I am using following configuration at Service Side**: -

[image]
and following

**Note: ClientCredientialType="`UserName`" and userNamePasswordValidationMode="`Windows`"**

As what I want is, that client should provide the username and password (credentials) which should be validated by windows at service side.

**Here is the auto-generated Client Configuration** : -

[image]

**Here is client Code to call the service**: -

[image]

But, even though I had entered the correct username and password (windows credentials), I am getting following error : -

[image]

Can anyone tell me what went wrong. Also note that I tried the same using **`negotiateServiceCredential="true"`** as well as **`negotiateServiceCredential="false"`**
But getting the same error.

Can anyone help.....

Comment: Can you please share also the exception message and not only the type?

Comment: @OscarJara thanks, as I found the problem behind the scene using full exception message. +1 for suggestion

Comment: nice to know that you made it work :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fine, I found the solution of the issue being faced by me. As I am using following behavior configuration at Client side: -

[image]

but I was not using it in the endpoint. So it was throwing negotiation exception. As it was trying to validate the certificate but there was no validation mode has been specified for the endpoint.

After using the behavior configuration named "**echoClaimBehavior**" in the endpoint, it is not validating the server certificate.

Thanks to **@Oscar Jara** who suggested to look at the full exception message instead of just the type.

This had shown me clearly what went wrong behind the scene.